# not calling unwind segue when button tapped

Tags: ios7, segue

I have a registration screen that is presented when my app first opened. When hitting register I want the app to send a request to the server and only after getting a response to trigger the unwind segue. But when I connect the "Register" button to the "Exit" green icon in storyboard and choose my unwind method, I guess that I set the segue to unwind when the button is tapped.

How do I **prevent** the segue from being performed on a tap?

I know that I can call the segue from the code by `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindFromRegisterToHome" sender:self];`

Comment: Disable the button until you get the response you need back from the server - then enable button? Or have I missed what you're trying to do?

Comment: I figured it out already :) just posted my answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Cool. Up vote from me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out I need to connect the ViewController (the yellow icon) to the Exit (green icon) and then to set a segue identifier. after that I can call the segue by `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindFromRegisterToHome" sender:self];`

Comment: I actually may need this in my project at times. Nice find!